# SELECT - SQL vs T-SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

My book says that

> There’s an interesting difference between standard SQL and T-SQL in terms of minimal >SELECT query requirements. According to standard SQL, a SELECT query must have at
>   minimum FROM and SELECT clauses. Conversely, T-SQL supports a SELECT query with only a
>   SELECT clause and without a FROM clause. Such a query is as if issued against an imaginary
>   table that has only one row. For example, the following query is invalid according to 
>   standard SQL but is valid according to T-SQL.

```
SELECT 10 AS col1, 'ABC' AS col2;

col1    col2
10      ABC
```

How could this feature possibly be useful ?

Comment: It's slightly better than `SELECT 10 AS col1, 'ABC' AS col2 from dual` ?

Comment: @ConradFrix - what is this dual ?

Comment: Mock table data, Inserting data into a table, representing meta data to name a few.

Comment: @blasto that's the way you would write that if you're using oracle

Comment: @Blasto in oracle it's a table with one column "DUMMY" with one row with a value of 'X'. Don't know what it is in the other RDMS's

Comment: "from dual"........(oracle)........drives me nuts.........

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not all data coming from a database might actually be from a database/table. Perhaps you want some metadata, or a server-side variable:

```
SELECT @server_side_variable;
```

Other DBs get around the restriction by having a virtual table named `DUAL`, so you have a `FROM` clause, but it doesn't actually point at any 'real' table in the database:

```
SELECT @server_side_variable FROM dual;
```

Comment: Perfect answer. Makes sense to me now. Wonder what MS achieved by by not using dual.

Comment: Same way everyone else who doesn't do the `dual` thing did it: they just wrote their SQL parser to NOT require a `from` clause.

Comment: I also use it to check the value of my own user variables at various points in a complex proc when I am running it in test mode.

Comment: The SQL definition @blasto had was technically the ANSI requirement.  T-SQL does this, as well as adding support for `SET` functionality, which is the way other, more-standardized RDBMSes will handle this.  E.g., MySQL requires a special syntax to select into variables, but the set syntax is virtually the same as what is provided.